# Building a Mixed Effects Logistic Regression in R for Panel/Longitudinal Data

Tags: logistic, repeated-measures, references

I have a dataset with `200` firms, each with `7` years of data on several numerical and categorical/factor variables, say, $(x_1,...,x_n)$, and a binary outcome variable $y$ (**not** fixed over time).

```
ID | Time | X1 ... Xn |  Y
1     1    .........     0
1     2    .........     0
1    ...
1     7    .........     1
```

These variables vary both by the firm ID and with time and hence I am looking at building a mixed effects logistic regression model.

Assuming that the predictors $(x_1,...,x_p)$ are the fixed predictors, and $(x_q,...,x_n)$ are those that vary with time, I currently have this formula:

```
model <- glmer(
              y ~ time + x1 + ... + xp + (1 + time + xq + ... + xn|ID,
              family = "binomial",
              data = longitudinalData
              )
```

Since the predictors vary by ID and with time, I wanted to ask the following:

1. How I can go about thinking about and specifying a model to predict $y$ while incorporating the ID and time?
2. Are there any practical examples/references I can look at to better understand how to model this classification problem?
3. Given that I have several predictors, is this the right modelling approach for the data I have described?

Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts - I think your model is reasonable, but in my experience entering this many random slopes may lead to overfitting and convergence problems. Especially if you have categorical predictors with many levels. I'd consider identifying 1 to 3 predictors which varying (by firm) slopes you are most interested in and just putting in their random slopes and leave the others as just fixed predictors.

Another thing is that I assume you have specified time as continuous. That also seems reasonable, as 7-level categorical predictor is cumbersome to interpret (at least IMO), but this assumes time has a linear effect, which may not be the case. Including a curvilinear time predictor may sometimes be a good idea to allow for a non-linear effect of time.

Third thing to consider is that within-firm observations may be more strongly correlated between adjacent years than, say years 1 and 7 so you may want to consider specifying a within-cluster correlation structure that takes into account this possible autoregressive correlation structure (you can do that for instance using the nlme package).

Comment: Thanks so much! A quick follow up question to your first point - I have close to a 1000 predictors and will soon have data on a much larger number of firms (close to 14,000), would it be reasonable to randomly subset the data and work with the reduced size subset?

Comment: Wow, that's an amazing amount of data! I never have that large sets so no great insight, but I believe a common way to deal with this is to split the data, as you suggest, and use some type of penalized regression (LASSO, ridge, elastic net) on one part to find out what predictors are most important, and then create a model based on this and test it on the remaining subset of data. Maybe it would be worthwhile to ask a new question about this, as how to deal with 1000 predictors is a separate issue from how to deal with glmer design :)

Comment: Thanks again! Yes, it's a lot of data and I'm really excited to play around with it and I have asked a new question (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/633663/variable-selection-for-longitudinal-data-with-a-binary-outomce)

Answer (score 1):

As Sointu pointed out already, it's problematic to let all your predictors have a random influence across firms. Do you really (theoretically) expect them to have a random influence? If there is no theory embedded reason, you could indeed start with fixed effects only. And next, maybe one by one, add a random effect to see if that would lead to a significantly better fit in terms of deviance; or examine if the 200 different slopes of X1 are "substantially" different. E.g. use coef() after estimating random slopes for only X1, to see if the 200 slopes or very different only slightly. However, adding another random slope for X2 could change things for the slopes of X1. So it remains difficult to choose on statistical grounds.

The correlation of your Y variable values between a pair of time points should also be modelled, again like Sointu mentioned. Having a random intercept and a random slope of time, would already lead to a particular correlation structure, which may be flexible enough for your data. With a random quadratic time influence, it would become even more flexible, but also more difficult to estimate and maybe not converge... Using nlme to obtain e.g. the AR1 structure would not work, as far as I know, because you do not have continuous data, which gls expects.

Forgot to mention that, because you use logistic, with adding a random intercept and slope of time, you model the correlations between the logodds of pairs of time points, which then leads to correlations between the observed Y values. However, I do not know what the exact relation is between the (modelled) logodds correlations and Y correlations.