# Variable Selection for Longitudinal Data with a Binary Outomce

Tags: feature-selection, panel-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a large longitudinal dataset (`100,000` observations) with firm IDs and Years with about `1000` features (most numeric and some factor). I have been running some classification tasks (random forest, xgboost, svm) on this data using a small subset of the available features. I want to be able to use the models to do some feature selection/ variable importance, however, running these models using all or most of the available predictors does not seem feasible.

What are the possible methods I can employ to select pertinent features, within the context of a longitudinal dataset, where features vary with by ID's but also with time.

Do I bite the bullet and allow these models to run on all features and then check variable importance and other metrics? Or are there some exploratory data analysis steps I can take prior to subset the features?

EDIT: Would it perhaps make sense to run random forests on subsets of features, for example `100` features at a time, thus, `10` RF models and use variable importance on each of them to get a sense of what predictors I can finally employ?